# Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter - redirects in the root but not subdirectories?

Tags: mod-rewrite, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using the Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter with Tomcat 7. I would like to shorten a bunch of URLs in the root folder but without messing up the subfolders etc...

e.g. I have something like...

```
/
/include/
/admin/
    page.jsp
    ...
/site/
    page.jsp
    ...
etc...
```

I would like to do something like:

```
^/$  >>  /site/page.jsp?handle=home
^/(.*) >> /site/page.jsp?handle=$1
```

But how can I exclude the subdirectories? e.g. /admin still needs to work with the files inside.

I could explicitly redirect the subdirs to another location. But this is not so elegant.

I could also use another subdir - e.g. ^/s/(.*) but I'd like them to be off root for usability.

```
/
/features
/examples
/support
etc...
```

What's the best way to do this kind of thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just match anything that doesn't include a slash, like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^$ /site/page.jsp?handle=home [L]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ /site/page.jsp?handle=$0 [L]
```